# How to let OkHttpClient.Dispatcher consume okhttp3.Request in LIFO(last in first out) order?

Tags: android, okhttp, requestdispatcher, lifo

## Goal:

Last enqueued `okhttp3.Call` is executed first

---

## Tried solution: LIFO `Executor` (not work)

I have found a solution for a LIFO `Executor`([Executor Service with LIFO ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107609/executor-service-with-lifo-ordering)), and applied this kind of `Executor` into `OkHttpClient` by this way

```
private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(
        Dispatcher(ThreadPoolExecutor(..., LifoLinkedBlockingDequeue<Runnable>()))
    ).build()
```

But, this **didn't work**.

#### Analysis

After tracing source code in `okhttp3.Dispatcher`, I found that:

1. First, every enqueued `Call` is added into `(private final Deque<AsyncCall> readyAsyncCalls = new ArrayDeque<>())` in `Dispatcher.java`"
2. Then, those `Call`s are moved from `readyAsyncCalls` to the blocking deque of `Executor` in **FIFO** order
3. Finally, `Call`s in `Executor` are executed in **LIFO** order

In my case, tremendous `Call`s are produced at the same time, and there are relatively less threads consuming them.

--> Most `Call`s are queued in `Dispatcher` instead of in `Executor` at a moment

--> LIFO `Executor` doesn't play the effect

#### Example

```
| Dispatcher: 1,2,3,4,5 | Executor:    | executing:    | done:          |
| Dispatcher: 2,3,4,5   | Executor:1   | executing:    | done:          |
| Dispatcher: 4,5       | Executor:2,3 | executing:1   | done:          |
| Dispatcher: 5         | Executor:4   | executing:3,2 | done:1         |
| Dispatcher:           | Executor:5   | executing:4   | done:1,3,2     |
| Dispatcher:           | Executor:    | executing:5   | done:1,3,2,4   |
| Dispatcher:           | Executor:    | executing:    | done:1,3,2,4,5 |
```

- `Call`s are moved from `Dispatcher` to `Executor` in FIFO order, and this procedure is very "inefficient".
- `Call`s from `Executor` to executing state is in LIFO order. But there are few `Call`s in `Executor`, LIFO effect is not obvious.

---

Does anyone know other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Build your own LIFO queue in front of OkHttp’s dispatcher. It accepts calls and holds them until they're ready to be executed. When they are, post them on the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason why it's INEFFICIENT to move requests from `Dispatcher` to `Executor` is: there are two maximums for number of moved requests at a time.

```
// okhttp3.Dispatcher
for (Iterator<AsyncCall> i = readyAsyncCalls.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    //do something...    

    if (runningAsyncCalls.size() >= maxRequests) break; // Max capacity.
    if (runningCallsForHost(asyncCall) >= maxRequestsPerHost) continue; // Host max capacity.
    //do something...
}
```

---

## Sol

Set a greater value for `Dispatcher.maxRequests` and `Dispatcher.maxRequestPerHost`

So that every new incoming request can be moved to executor as soon as possible

--> to give full scope to the characteristic of queue passed into `Executor`

But... I'm not sure that whether large maximum will cause any side effects...