# How to make an ExecutorService act as a LIFO

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, lifo

I have a client application in `Java Swing` which displays a list of pictures.
Pictures are displayed with `JLabel`. The thumbnails are cached in a `Firebird` database and returned by a web-service `Soap/MTOM`.

[Video of the behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DFYAwON6FbyI6p-BLDgQmHD2mxQ46Gua/view?usp=sharing)

I create all the `Jlabel` in a `SwingWorker` and retrieve the thumbnail in the paint method of the `Jlabel` (if icon not yet assigned).
I am using an Java `ExecutorService` to call the web-services which return each thumbnail.

As you can see in the video, when I scroll down a big amount lines, I have to wait that all thumbnails in `JLabel` visible during scrolling are fetched.

The `ExecutorService` is instantiated like this:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
```

The piece of code called from `paint` method when `getIcon() == null` is:

```java
executor.execute(new FutureTask<Void>(() -> {
    var image = EdmWS.getInstance().getThumbnail(thumbnail.date, thumbnail.name, sizeThumbnail);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    label.invalidate();
}, null));
```

Is there a way to have an executor working like a LIFO (last in first out) to get the thumbnails of displayed `JLabel` as soon as possible?

---

Thank for your comment, [Executor Service with LIFO ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107609/executor-service-with-lifo-ordering)

```java
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
        return super.offerFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return super.offerFirst(e, timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Runnable e) {
        return super.offerFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Runnable e) throws InterruptedException {
        super.putFirst(e);
    }
});
```

do the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107609/executor-service-with-lifo-ordering